# Problem in inserting a module into ubuntu kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am using Ubuntu-11.04 OS. i wrote a basic interactive kernel module mid.c

```
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/init.h>

static int __init insert(void)
{
  pr_info(" The module is inserted into the kernel \n");
  return 0;
}

static void __exit remove(void)
{
  pr_info("the module is removed from kernel \n");
}

module_init(insert);
module_exit(remove);
```

i can compile the module by using the command

```
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.38-8-generic/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

but when i try to insert the module using the command

```
insmod mod.ko
```

an error occurs saying :

```
cannot insert mod.ko permission denied
```

Comment: Did you google the error message? That would have been probably quicker than asking here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to add a `sudo` before insmod